# How to see the outline of images in a Fireworks document?

Tags: adobe-fireworks

I have a number of images in a Fireworks document. When I select them they have a blue outline which tells me exactly how big the image is (they contain transparency).

How can I see this outline without actually selecting the images? I want to see how large all the images are and be able to move them one by one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Outline View` feature was removed in Fireworks CS5. If you can get a copy of CS5, hit <kbd>Command/Control</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to view all object edges.

Do you have a copy of Illustrator? You could copy your image assets into that, lay them out there (using Illustrator's [Outline Mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6329a.html#WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-6320a)) and then paste them back into Fireworks?